# Ionic 3 issue with Adding Push Notification

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I am working on my app to add Push Notifications. I am using **phonegap-plugin-push@2.1.3** for my project. Everything is working well but when I add **Push** to the **Provider**, app start to give error.

**app.module.ts**

```
import {ErrorHandler, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {AppVersion} from '@ionic-native/app-version';
import {CallNumber} from '@ionic-native/call-number';
import {Device} from '@ionic-native/device';
import {File} from '@ionic-native/file';
import {FileOpener} from '@ionic-native/file-opener';
import {FileTransfer} from '@ionic-native/file-transfer';
import {GoogleMaps} from '@ionic-native/google-maps';
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';
import {Media} from '@ionic-native/media';
import { Push } from '@ionic-native/push';
import {SplashScreen} from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import {StatusBar} from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import {IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule} from 'ionic-angular';
import {App} from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ..........[declarations]
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(App)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    ..........[component]
  ],
  providers: [
    Push,
    ......... [other provider]
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

[image: Error During App Compile]

Comment: Check this link for push notifcation http://tphangout.com/ionic-2-push-notifications-with-firebase/

Comment: @AniruddhThakor have done the same but still no luck

Comment: I have implemented same as this link and my app is working,you must have miss something.try to uninstall the plugin and install it again and then clean your gradle  first then run it again ,it might work .

Comment: Error indicating plugin not installed properly.

Comment: try importing push as
import { Push } from '@ionic-native/push/ngx';

Answer (score 0):

Change the imports like this

```
import { Push, PushObject, PushOptions } from '@ionic-native/push/ngx';
```

> The imports path should be from the ionic native module.**ngx** is
>   missing in your imports

Refer ionic documentation
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push/